# Getting an error when using Shared Preferences in a service

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to access Shared Preferences in a Service but it keeps throwing me this error and the app crashes: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.ct.kitapp.PubNubFirebase: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference`

This is firebase instance service:

```
public class PubNubFirebase extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PubNubUserFile";
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String pubKey = sharedPref.getString("pubkey","default");
    String subKey = sharedPref.getString("subkey","default");

    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.i("FireBaseID", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        try {
            JsonObject jsonToken = new JsonObject();
            jsonToken.addProperty("tokenJson", refreshedToken);
            Log.i("jsonToken", String.valueOf(jsonToken));
            sendTokenToPubNub(jsonToken);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("jsonToken", "Exception: " + e);
        }



    }

    private void sendTokenToPubNub(JsonObject refreshedToken) {
        //String msg = "{registrationToken : " + refreshedToken + "}";
//        PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
//        pnConfiguration.setPublishKey(pubKey);
//        pnConfiguration.setSubscribeKey(subKey);
        //Log.i("firepub",pubKey);
        //PubNub pubnub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);

        PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
        pnConfiguration.setPublishKey(pubKey);
        pnConfiguration.setSubscribeKey(subKey);

        PubNub pubnub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);
        pubnub.publish().channel("test_channel3").message(refreshedToken).async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(PNPublishResult result, PNStatus status) {
                // Check whether request successfully completed or not.
                if (!status.isError()) {
                    Log.i("FireToken", String.valueOf(status.getStatusCode()));
                    Log.i("FireToken", status.getCategory().toString());
                    // Message successfully published to specified channel.
                }
                // Request processing failed.
                else {
                    Log.i("FireToken", String.valueOf(status.getStatusCode()));
                    Log.i("FireToken", status.getCategory().toString());
                    Log.i("FireToken", status.getErrorData().toString());
                    // Handle message publish error. Check 'category' property to find out possible issue
                    // because of which request did fail.
                    //
                    // Request can be resent using: [status retry];
                }
            }
        });
      }
    }
```

I need to access the PubNub keys from Shared Preferences to use inside the sendTokenToPubNub method when configuring PubNub. I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Full logcat:

```
11-29 20:08:00.749 825-871/? E/Sensors: sns_reg_la.c(188):reg read: offset 2304, num bytes: 1
11-29 20:08:00.750 767-1307/? E/qti_sensors_hal: processInd: pickup data: state: 1.000000 flag: 0.000000 SAM TS: 2802400084 HAL TS:85513644537973 elapsedRealtimeNano:85513705042098
11-29 20:08:00.754 825-871/? E/Sensors: sns_reg_la.c(188):reg read: offset 2304, num bytes: 1
11-29 20:08:00.761 767-767/? E/qti_sensors_hal: sendEnableReq:sensor(android.sensor.proximity) Sending enable to svc no:21
11-29 20:08:00.767 767-1309/? E/qti_sensors_hal: reportSingleEvent: prox data: 5.000305 raw:16.000000 2989118976.000000 SAM TS: 2756542590 HAL TS:84114184882746 elapsedRealtimeNano:85513722376733
11-29 20:08:00.772 767-767/? E/qti_sensors_hal: sendCancel:sensor(android.sensor.proximity) Sending cancel to svc no:21
11-29 20:08:00.773 961-2421/? E/fpc_fingerprint_hal: screen_state_loop screen ON 0
11-29 20:08:00.780 767-767/? E/qti_sensors_hal: sendEnableReq:sensor(android.sensor.proximity) Sending enable to svc no:21
11-29 20:08:00.786 767-1309/? E/qti_sensors_hal: reportSingleEvent: prox data: 5.000305 raw:16.000000 2989118976.000000 SAM TS: 2756542590 HAL TS:84114184882747 elapsedRealtimeNano:85513741396941
11-29 20:08:00.868 754-23867/? E/msm8974_platform: platform_get_snd_device_backend_index: no hw_interface set for device 69
11-29 20:08:00.868 754-23867/? E/audio_hw_utils: send_app_type_cfg_for_device: Couldn't get the backend index for snd device handset-mic-re-three ret=-22
11-29 20:08:00.869 754-23867/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
11-29 20:08:00.869 754-23867/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE Returned = -19


                                              [ 11-29 20:08:00.869   754:23867 D/         ]
                                              Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 00000091 
11-29 20:08:00.869 754-23867/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
11-29 20:08:00.889 1415-3827/? E/DeviceKeyHandler: receive keyguard done, process gesture action
11-29 20:08:00.902 767-2153/? E/qti_sensors_hal: sendCancel:sensor(com.oneplus.sensor.pocket) Sending cancel to svc no:31
11-29 20:08:00.958 767-2153/? E/qti_sensors_hal: sendCancel:sensor(android.sensor.proximity) Sending cancel to svc no:21
11-29 20:08:00.961 767-2153/? E/qti_sensors_hal: sendEnableReq:sensor(android.sensor.proximity) Sending enable to svc no:21
11-29 20:08:00.965 6134-6134/? E/ContentDetectionService: updateSceneDetectionState() - No SceneDetector
11-29 20:08:01.026 767-1309/? E/qti_sensors_hal: reportSingleEvent: prox data: 5.000305 raw:18.000000 2989118976.000000 SAM TS: 2802411071 HAL TS:85513979835821 elapsedRealtimeNano:85513980872462
11-29 20:08:02.128 3641-23562/? E/ctxmgr: [AppIntervalImpl]closeInterval: ongoing
11-29 20:08:02.137 3641-23562/? E/ctxmgr: [ProducerStatusImpl]updateStateForNewContextData: inactive, contextName=6
11-29 20:08:03.754 32548-32548/? E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-29 20:08:03.767 32548-32548/? E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-29 20:08:05.685 32548-32548/? E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
11-29 20:08:05.685 32548-32548/? E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
11-29 20:08:05.701 793-2427/? E/SurfaceFlinger: Failed to find layer (SurfaceView - InputMethod#0) in layer parent (no-parent).
11-29 20:08:05.702 793-876/? E/SurfaceFlinger: Failed to find layer (Background for - SurfaceView - InputMethod#0) in layer parent (no-parent).
11-29 20:08:06.633 1415-2674/? E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
11-29 20:08:06.635 1415-2674/? E/BoostFramework: Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
11-29 20:08:06.662 19772-19772/? E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
11-29 20:08:06.663 19772-19772/? E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
11-29 20:08:07.521 1415-1465/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast action_change_isolate_application_theme from system uid 1000 pkg null
                                                  java.lang.Throwable
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:20827)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:21503)
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:21645)
                                                      at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$6.run(PackageManagerService.java:14631)
                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
                                                      at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
11-29 20:08:07.524 4989-5028/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute viewStreamItemActivity
11-29 20:08:07.525 4944-4988/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute viewStreamItemActivity
11-29 20:08:07.531 4989-5028/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
11-29 20:08:07.532 4944-4988/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
11-29 20:08:07.552 2689-2689/? E/OPUtils: removeMultiApp ,cloudthat.ct.kitapp
11-29 20:08:07.583 2788-23934/? E/OPSkin:ThemeIntentService: cloudthat.ct.kitapp
11-29 20:08:07.588 3741-3741/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: Next Tag=services
11-29 20:08:07.588 3741-3741/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: 1invalidateCache:WriteServiceStateToFile
11-29 20:08:07.588 3741-3741/? E/RegisteredServicesCache:  Writing service state Data Always
11-29 20:08:07.613 4731-4731/? E/Finsky: [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bk.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
11-29 20:08:07.791 32548-23961/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: true
11-29 20:08:07.794 32548-23962/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: true
11-29 20:08:07.807 3572-23958/? E/DropboxRealtime: Unknown package: cloudthat.ct.kitapp
                                                   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: cloudthat.ct.kitapp
                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1946)
                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
                                                       at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getInstallerPackageName(IPackageManager.java:4207)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getInstallerPackageName(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1972)
                                                       at agdj.a(:com.google.android.gms@11746440:45)
                                                       at agct.a(:com.google.android.gms@11746440:3)
                                                       at agbv.a(:com.google.android.gms@11746440:10)
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedChimeraService.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@11746440:15)
                                                       at buh.handleMessage(Unknown Source:6)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
11-29 20:08:08.645 776-862/? E/ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: perf_lock_rel: updated /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/../../../clkscale_enable with 1
                                                       return value 2
11-29 20:08:15.671 755-6076/? E/vendor.qti.bluetooth@1.0-wake_lock: Release wakelock is released 
11-29 20:08:17.447 755-6076/? E/vendor.qti.bluetooth@1.0-wake_lock: Release wakelock is released 
11-29 20:08:20.596 825-871/? E/Sensors: sns_reg_la.c(188):reg read: offset 2304, num bytes: 1
11-29 20:08:20.755 1415-18585/? E/LocationManagerService: requestLocationUpdates: uid=10075, pid=25558, provider=gps, package=com.google.android.apps.maps listener= android.location.ILocationListener$Stub$Proxy@36c6985 intent= null
11-29 20:08:20.763 825-871/? E/Sensors: sns_reg_la.c(188):reg read: offset 2304, num bytes: 1
11-29 20:08:20.777 825-871/? E/Sensors: sns_reg_la.c(188):reg read: offset 2304, num bytes: 1
11-29 20:08:21.328 1415-2671/? E/LocationManagerService: removeUpdates: uid=10075, pid=25558, intent=null, package=com.google.android.apps.maps listener android.location.ILocationListener$Stub$Proxy@f0f4471 intent= null
11-29 20:08:21.337 825-871/? E/Sensors: sns_reg_la.c(297):reg write: offset 10752, num bytes: 126
11-29 20:08:21.347 825-871/? E/Sensors: sns_reg_la.c(297):reg write: offset 1792, num bytes: 24
11-29 20:08:24.165 767-2153/? E/qti_sensors_hal: sendEnableReq:sensor(android.sensor.significant_motion) Sending enable to svc no:40
11-29 20:08:24.194 767-2153/? E/qti_sensors_hal: sendCancel:sensor(android.sensor.significant_motion) Sending cancel to svc no:40
11-29 20:08:32.303 924-31289/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1573728457.tmp: No such file or directory
11-29 20:08:32.347 4989-5028/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute viewStreamItemActivity
11-29 20:08:32.347 4944-4988/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute viewStreamItemActivity
11-29 20:08:32.357 4944-4988/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
11-29 20:08:32.412 3741-3741/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: Next Tag=services
11-29 20:08:32.413 3741-3741/? E/RegisteredServicesCache: 1invalidateCache:WriteServiceStateToFile
11-29 20:08:32.413 3741-3741/? E/RegisteredServicesCache:  Writing service state Data Always
11-29 20:08:32.429 4989-5028/? E/ExternalAccountType: Unsupported attribute readOnly
11-29 20:08:32.493 1415-2671/? E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
11-29 20:08:32.495 1415-2671/? E/BoostFramework: Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
11-29 20:08:32.514 4731-4731/? E/Finsky: [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bk.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
11-29 20:08:32.529 1415-18582/? E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
11-29 20:08:32.530 1415-18582/? E/BoostFramework: Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
11-29 20:08:32.565 24145-24162/? E/zygote64: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
11-29 20:08:32.883 1415-3800/? E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: perfIOPrefetchStart [int, class java.lang.String]
11-29 20:08:32.884 1415-3800/? E/BoostFramework: Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
11-29 20:08:33.449 24145-24145/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: cloudthat.ct.kitapp, PID: 24145
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service cloudthat.ct.kitapp.PubNubFirebase: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3554)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1778)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:168)
                                                       at cloudthat.ct.kitapp.PubNubFirebase.<init>(PubNubFirebase.java:24)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3551)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1778) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Show the full logcat, please

Comment: `this.getSharedPreferences` won't work outside of an instance  method

Comment: I wonder if OP will understand yet again such cryptic answer.

Comment: I've tried various solutions from different posts still can't seem to figure it out. I've edited the post with the logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize anything relying on Context in the "onTokenRefresh" method. The context is not available before the service has been initialized. It's the same as working with an activites context before "onCreate" was called.

Comment: Got it thanks this helped clear some of my doubts. The thing is now the refreshed token isn't being published on the channel anymore.

Comment: Any exceptions when it happens/should happen?

Answer (score 0):

use `getBaseContext()` , like this:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences
```

Comment: I've already tried this and it throws the same error and crashes.

Comment: @BlackIce2107 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference,  Obviously the problem is the Context you're using to get the sharedPrefference